# How to split a string (using regex?) depending on digit/ not digit

Tags: python, regex, string, tokenize

I want to split a string into a list in python, depending on digit/ not digit.
For example,

```
5 55+6+  5/
```

should return

```
['5','55','+','6','+','5','/']
```

I have some code at the moment which loops through the characters in a string and tests them using re.match("\d") or ("\D"). I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

P.S: must be compatible with python 2.4

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. It's for a reverse polish notation calculator so I couldn't just assume there was always a space between the characters (didn't know there was a name for what I wanted to do until now though. Thanks for telling me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `+` between 6 and 5 needs to be matched (which you're missing),

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '5 55+6+ 5/'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[^\d\s]+', s)
['5', '55', '+', '6', '+', '5', '/']
```

Comment: Great pattern, but it seems like you may as well use findall. You also don't need the trailing `\s*` in the pattern, but it doesn't hurt either. +1

Comment: Thanks! re.findall was exactly what I was looking for. Used "[ ]+|\d+|^\d" in the end (need multiple consecutive digits together, but non digits separate).

Answer (score 2):

this one is simplest one :)

```
re.findall('\d+|[^\d]+','134aaaaa')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `findall` or `finditer`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[^\s\d]+', '5 55+6+ 5/')
['5', '55', '+', '6', '+', '5', '/']
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, you could do 2 splits:

```
re.split('\D+', mystring)

re.split('\d+', mystring)
```

However, from your input, it looks like it might be mathematical... in which case order would matter. :)

You are best off using `re.findall`, as in one of the other answers.

Comment: Yeah, it's for a reverse polish notation calculator - order definitely matters!